# Блокировка\удаление ведущих нулей в поле TextField

Tags: java, swing

Нужно блокировать ввод ведущих нулей программисту-пользователю и удалять ведущие нули в TextField,то есть чтобы они даже не вводились.Пример:user пишет в TextField "000012345"-->нажимаем кнопочку,магия-->брык,TextField становится "12345".У меня пока не получается, в бошку засунуть всё , пока ток так.

Юзаю это:

```
*тра-та-та код*

public JTextField cntrlVControlInput(JTextField temp) {
        if (temp.getDocument() instanceof AbstractDocument)
            ((AbstractDocument) temp.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new SpaceDocumentFilter());
        return temp;
    }

*тра-та-та код*

*юзаю этот класс*:
public class SpaceDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        public SpaceDocumentFilter() {
        }

        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if (string == null)
                return;
            replace(fb, offset, 0, string, attr);
        }

        public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
            replace(fb, offset, length, "", null);
        }

        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.replace(offset, length, checkInput(text, offset), attrs);
        }

        private String checkInput(String proposedValue, int offset) throws BadLocationException {
            return proposedValue.replaceAll("", "");
        }//^0+
        //^0+(?=\\\\d+$)
    }
//[\\s\\\\/'/"!~@#$№%^&*()_+=><:;.,\\\\[\\\\]{}^] - это на всё лишнее
//^0+ - перед этим if на ("\\d+")
//^0+(?=\\d+$)-последние две регулярочки в иннете откопал : [url]https://stackoverrun.com/ru/q/4314720[/url]

/*тра-та-та еще код*/

//еще это юзаю
public JTextField inputCheck(JTextField temp) {

        temp.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

                char key = e.getKeyChar();

                if (Character.isWhitespace(key))
                    e.consume();
                if ((key == '!' || (key == '~') || (key == '@') || (key == '#') || (key == '?') || (key == '$')
                        || (key == '%') || (key == '^') || (key == '&') || (key == '*') || (key == '(') || (key == ')')
                        || (key == '_') || (key == '+') || (key == '=') || (key == '-') || (key == '<') || (key == '>')
                        || (key == ':') || (key == ';') || (key == '.') || (key == '\\') || (key == '|') || (key == '[')
                        || (key == ']') || (key == '"') || (key == '\'') || (key == '}') || (key == '{')))
                    e.consume();
                if (Character.isAlphabetic(key))
                    e.consume();

                if (temp.getText().length() >= 10)
                    e.consume();
            }
        });
        return temp;
    }

*тра-та-та код*
```

Comment: В любом случае первое - вешаем слушатель на TextField. Если в ваш TextField допустимо вводить только цифры(иначе зачем от нулей избавляться), то можно при вводе следующего знака вычитывать значение из поля и преобразовывать его и Integer в блоке try-catch. При этом catch скажет о том, что пользователь ввел не цифру. При этом можно, например, ввести переменную, запоминающую предыдущий ввод и устанавливать ее значение в поле. Если же catch не сработал, то пользователь по прежнему вводит цифры. Теперь надо лишь преобразовать Integer снова в String и установить в TextField, нулей не будет

Comment: Простите, но теперь я видел все.... Сделай обычный перевод в число, джава понимает и убирает нули вначале, затем число верни в строку (если так нужно)